# micro:bit not responding to AB button presses

Tags: bbc-microbit

So I used this micro:bit for a while and it never had a problem but for some reason one day I started it and it refused to respond to my A+B button presses even though I did not change the code in any way. Both pressing A and B work but not both of them together. I also have a sparkfun moto:bit attachment board as well though I don't think it has any problems with it.

Comment: [When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Hardware:
Did you touch the boards front/backside? If you did the inner connection is damaged and the microbit is done this can be even when the buttons work separately.

Or there is maybe  some connection issues in the board try to blow on it or just look if there are scratches
Or dust on the connection ports on your sparkfun.
That could block the connection
(you can try to blow on the connection ports to get of the dust)

Software:

I am less good in this but it could be that they put an software update to make things faster, better, etc. And encoded it differently

End:
From my experience I think it’s wear and tear because even a scratch on the wrong location could ruin a whole board

Maby try an enclosure like this[the left one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd7ml.jpg)
That saved my life